# How to update a column based on the calculation of a column and a variable in a single SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table that represents "products" and has 3 columns: "Product ID", "warehouse" quantity and "shop" quantity and want to subtract ordered quantities in a single query, first from the warehouse, then from the shop and if more quantity is needed then go below '0' in the warehouse.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`, `quantity_warehouse`, `quantity_shop`, ) VALUES
(1001, 5, 3),
(1002, 5, 3),
(1003, 5, 3)
```

1. If I order 3 products 1001 then 3 will be subtracted from warehouse
   so: warehouse=2, shop=3
2. If I order 7 products 1002 then 5 will be subtracted from warehouse
   and 2 from shop so: warehouse=0, shop=1
3. If I order 9 products 1003 then 6 will be subtracted from warehouse
   and all (3) from shop so: warehouse=-1, shop=0

What I have done so far but does not work and updates with '0':

```
UPDATE
    products
SET 
    quantity_warehouse= CASE
        WHEN ((quantity_warehouse+quantity_shop)<'#ordered_quantity') THEN quantity_warehouse=(quantity_warehouse-('#ordered_quantity'-quantity_shop))
        WHEN (quantity_warehouse<'#ordered_quantity') THEN quantity_warehouse=0
        ELSE quantity_warehouse=(quantity_warehouse-'#ordered_quantity') END,
    quantity_shop   = CASE
        WHEN ((quantity_warehouse+quantity_shop)<'#ordered_quantity') THEN quantity_shop=0
        WHEN (quantity_shop<('#ordered_quantity'-quantity_warehouse)) THEN quantity_shop=0
        ELSE quantity_shop=(quantity_shop-('#ordered_quantity'-quantity_warehouse)) END
WHERE
    product_id = '1001'
```

Pseudocode example that works:

```
if (warehouse<order){
    if (shop<(order-warehouse)){
        shop=0;
    }else{
        shop=shop-(order-warehouse);
    }
    warehouse=0;
}else{
    warehouse=warehouse-order;
}
```

What should the query look like? Are the "CASE" appropriate?

Comment: please provida a table with dat a full [mre]

Comment: Forgive my lack of clarity. I edited the post and I hope it is better formatted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set your values to the result of a comparison

Ok, that took me a while.

So when you first overwrite the quantity_warehouse , mysql takes the new value  and tries to update the second

So we need to save the "old" values and use them

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (`product_id` int ,`quantity_warehouse` int, `quantity_shop` int );
INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `quantity_warehouse`, `quantity_shop` ) VALUES
(1001, 5, 3),
(1002, 5, 3),
(1003, 5, 3);

UPDATE
    products CROSS JOIN (SELECT (quantity_warehouse+quantity_shop) sumw,quantity_warehouse  as qw FROM products WHERE  `product_id` = '1001') t1
SET 
    quantity_warehouse= CASE
        WHEN (t1.sumw<'7') THEN 
              (quantity_warehouse-('7' + 0 -quantity_shop))
        WHEN (quantity_warehouse<'7') THEN 0
        ELSE (quantity_warehouse-'7') END,
    quantity_shop   = CASE
        WHEN ((t1.sumw)<'7') THEN 0
        WHEN (quantity_shop<('7' -t1.qw)) THEN 0
        ELSE (quantity_shop-('7'  -t1.qw)) END
WHERE
    product_id = '1001'
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

| product_id | quantity_warehouse | quantity_shop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0 | 1 |
| 1002 | 5 | 3 |
| 1003 | 5 | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exfkgCJpH9X4ped4S2PGpj/6)

Comment: Oh, yeah! I understood my mistake. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. However, the example should return for product_id 1001, quantity_warehouse=1 (because 5-(7-3)=1,not 0) and quantity_shop=0

Comment: @WhiteHatMan i change the query so that it updates the correct values

Comment: That is it. CROSS JOIN did it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: for multiple product_ids to update you need a inner join on the product_id

Comment: I am looking for one row update per query, so I think I am ok and already do tests. Still, I learned something new! Thanx again.